# Movie with stranded astronaut. Alien girl saves him with oxygen plants

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

The movie was about an astronaut who crashes on a planet. He was running out of oxygen but he was unconscious and so this alien girl found him and the suit told her to find a net and put a bunch of like plants to put oxygen around the suit so the suit can collect oxygen. The suit was able to learn different types of languages and that's why the suit knew how to talk to her.

I don't remember if it was animated or not.

The suit even scanned the room the girl took him to so it can make sure that the net she made with plants had enough oxygen.

Comment: **His spacesuit** told her to collect plants?

Comment: Sounds like Battle for Terra, but can't really remember the spacesuit part. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9U30QfMOpCU

Comment: @Bosc Looks like a low budget knockoff of Avatar

Comment: @Machavity: Except that [*Battle for Terra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_for_Terra) was released in 2007, 2 years before [*Avatar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar_(2009_film)). Also, I've watched both films and they are actually not that similar. In particular, *Battle for Terra* has a lot more internal power struggle among the alien culture, as far as I remember.

Comment: It is not like Avatar at all

Comment: Battle for Terra came up a couple of months ago in response to an earlier question.  Does that make this a duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

This is [Battle for Terra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_for_Terra). She builds him an oxygenated environment because she thinks he'll help save her dad.

> After Mala's own father, Roven (Dennis Quaid) is abducted she goads a ship into tailing her and lures it into a trap, which causes it to crash. Afterward, she saves the life of the pilot, revealed to be a human, an officer named Lieutenant Jim Stanton (Luke Wilson). After his personal robot assistant named Giddy (David Cross) warns Mala that Stanton will die without a supply of oxygen (which the Terrian atmosphere does not contain), she creates an oxygen generator and fills a tent with oxygen so that Jim can breathe, and eventually convinces Giddy to teach her human language. Giddy informs Mala that the mysterious object is a generation ship called The Ark, containing humans from Earth.